# CakeEmail - Send HTML and Plain-text message manually

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to send a plain-text and html email from CakePHP using the built-in function, but without touching the .ctp files.

Here's what i want from the CakeEmail :

```
//Send email to user
$email = new CakeEmail('default');
$email->to($customers['Customer']['email']);
$email->subject('Password reset');
$email->htmlMessage('<div>Reset the password</div>');
$email->textMessage('Password the reset');
$email->send();
```

But apparently, these functions don't exist, so anyone know of an alternative solution?
I doesn't want to touch the Email folder of CakePHP, as the email layout & content is generated dynamically.

Cake version 2.0.6

Bascially, i want a CakePHP version of this code : http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/2959/sending-htmlplain-text-emails
Capable of sending both HTML and Plain-text email

Comment: Not clear from your question what excatly you want ? Have you go through http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html ?

Comment: cake2.2? please always specify your version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its actually pretty simple.
I do it this way (with html text):

```
$this->Email->emailFormat('both');

$text = trim(strip_tags($html));
$this->Email->viewVars(compact('text', 'html'));

if ($this->Email->send()) {...}
```

you just need to echo the variables in the corresponding view ctps